# how to grep a string from a txt file in Python

Tags: python

im trying to grep from a file a string 'MB/s' ,below is my code

```
import re
raw = open('C:\\Python27\\BCF013K.txt',encoding='UTF-8')
data=raw.read()
raw.close()

print(re.match(r'MB/s',data))
```

not sure why i am keep seeing this error. My file is simple text file see below:

```
MB/s = 1,000,000 bytes/s [SATA/600 = 600,000,000 bytes/s]

KB = 1000 bytes, KiB = 1024 bytes
```

its keeps saying `None` when i run the code

Comment: if you `print(data)` before the regex line, what happens?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python -- re.match vs. re.search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346076/python-re-match-vs-re-search)

Comment: try to print data please, your regex is correct and works on a string

Comment: @progmatico it all works fine for me. I had the same input as above and the same regex

Comment: @JonathanR yea his regex is working on the string defined by his exemple, so the problem lies elsewhere, probably on the reading part

Comment: True, @JonathanR my comment wasn't right.

Comment: The problem must lie in the file you are reading

Comment: here is what i see :                  RESTART: C:\Users\RAKhan\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.5\asadkhan.py 
None
>>>

Comment: You don't mention what error you are seeing. Your regex only searches the first line of the file. If you want the whole file, add the MULTILINE flag.

Comment: there is no error , it just show the word None as output, my Python is 3.2.0 , if that has any relevance here

Comment: try `re.match(r'MB/s',data,flags=re.MULTILINE)`

Comment: adding MULTILINE flag didnt help

Comment: if i print data before regex interestingly i see it prints both lines

Comment: How about posting `print(repr(data))` so we all see exactly what's in the file.

Comment: by using print (repr(data)) i see this , i dont know what is this 
      \x00B\x00/\x00s\x00 \x00=\x00 \x001\x00,\x000\x000\x000\x00,\x000\x000\x000\x00 \x00b\x00y\x00t\x00e\x00s\x00/\x00s\x00 \x00[\x00S\x00A\x00T\x00A\x00/\x006\x000\x000\x00 \x00=\x00 \x006\x000\x000\x00,\x000\x000\x000\x00,\x000\x000\x000\x00 \x00b\x00y\x00t\x00e\x00s\x00/\x00s\x00]\x00\n\x00\n\x00K\x00B\x00 \x00=\x00 \x001\x000\x000\x000\x00 \x00b\x00y\x00t\x00e\x00s\x00,\x00 \x00K\x00i\x00B\x00 \x00=\x00 \x001\x000\x002\x004\x00 \x00b\x00y\x00t\x00e\x00s\x00\n\x00\n\x00

Comment: That's a utf-16 file, not utf-8. But it also appears to be missing the initial BOM (byte order mark) or it would have failed when trying a utf-8 decode. Try opening as `open('C:\\Python27\\BCF013K.txt',encoding='UTF-16-LE')`

Comment: ...and pay heed to the linked duplicate from @zwer because your code is only looking for "MB/s" at the beginning of the file, in which case you are better off using `data.startswith("MB/s")`.

Comment: @tdelaney this worked. You are a magician  :) Thank you very much for taking your precious time and help me out with this problem. Its working for me now